# What is the difference between the Temporal multithreading and Super-threading?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, cpu, cpu-architecture

There are two terms:

- [Temporal multithreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_multithreading): In fine-grained temporal multithreading, the main processor pipeline may contain multiple threads, with context switches effectively occurring between pipe stages (e.g., in the [barrel processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_processor)).  A barrel processor is a CPU that switches between threads of execution on every cycle.
- [Super-threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-threading): is a type of multithreading that enables different threads to be executed by a single processor without truly executing them at the same time.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_multithreading) This qualifies it as time-sliced or temporal multithreading rather than simultaneous multithreading (SMT). It is motivated by the observation that the processor's functional units are occasionally left idle while executing instructions from one thread due to long-latency events. Super-threading seeks to make use of the otherwise unused processor cycles by executing instructions from another thread until the previous thread is ready to resume execution.

Is the main difference between TM and ST, that Temporal multithreading (fine-grained) uses [C-slowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-slowing) and switches between threads of execution on every cycle, but Super-threading  switches between threads not every cycle and only when processor's functional units are left idle while executing instructions from one thread due to long-latency events?

What is the difference between the Temporal multithreading (fine-grained) and Super-threading?

Comment: From a *very brief* search (and *some* familiarity with computer architecture) it seems that super-threading was first used in Shuichi Sakai et al.'s "Super-threading: Architectural and Software Mechanisms for Optimizing Parallel Computation" with a much broader sense of hardware support for threading. The term is not commonly used (as far as I am aware) in the computer architecture community. Temporal multithreading includes coarse-grained (typically switch-on-event MT) and fine-grained (including barrel processing and more flexible cycle-by-cycle scheduling) MT.

Comment: @Paul A. Clayton The term ST is rarely used. Is it possible because super-threading (ST) provides instructions only for one pipeline (ALU), but simultaneous multithreading (SMT) for multiple pipelines (ALUs)? I.e. ST takes advantage only for stalls (cache miss, branch misprediction, or data dependency), but modern CPUs are also superscalar architecture, and instead of ST used SMT to take advantage of superscalar architecture. For example Hyper-Threading - is Intel's proprietary simultaneous multithreading (SMT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporal multi-threading could be in form of fine-grain or coarse-grain multi-threading. Fine-grain multithreading switches contexts at fixed fine-grain interval (e.g. every cycle). Coarse-grain multithreading switches contexts on long-latency events (e.g. LLC cache misses).

Simultaneous multithreading, on the other hand, does not have any notion of thread switching. Multiple threads can run concurrently.

A picture is worth a thousand words. Take a look at slides 5 to 7 [here](http://ece757.ece.wisc.edu/lect03-cores-multithread.pdf). It has pictures for all 3 methods and compares them nicely.

As other people have said, super-threading is not a common term and it seems similar to coarse-grain TM to me.

Comment: Thank you, yes this is good slides. We can consider that Super-Threading the same as Temporal multithreading (coarse-grain). I.e. types of multithreading is vary as follows - from shared anything to shared nothing in CPU-core between threads: **None** (fully software multithreading), **TM (fine-grained)** in barrel processors, **TM (coars-grained) - Super Threading**, **SMT** - Hyper Threading, **CMT** (Chip Multithreading) - multicore with shared expensive resource (single FPU on some cores), **CMP** (Chip Multiprocessors) - multicore with shared Last Level Cache & interconnect.

Comment: Can we say, that modern Intel CPUs, for example, Intel Core i7 is both CMP and SMT?

Comment: @Alex, as far as I know, yes. Almost all x86 processors are CMP these days (I cannot think of any single-core x86 CPU). The same is true for SMT. Some are 2-way SMT, some are 4-way SMT. Note that Intel uses the term Hyperthreading for SMT.   BTW, take a look at Stanford CPU database for your reference. http://cpudb.stanford.edu/